# Probability of a defective device

Tags: probability, statistics

A manufacturer of household devices reports that on average $10$% of its products are defective.  In a random sample of $5$, what is the probability that:

$P(D)=0.1$ $P(D^c)=0.9$

(a) Exactly $3$ devices are defective

C$5\choose 3$ = $\frac{5!}{3!}$ but I don't know where to implement the appropriate probabilities

(b) None are defective

C$5\choose 0$

I don't know the other two at all

(c) Less than $2$ devices are defective

(d) More than $3$ devices are defective

Comment: The notation is either $\mathrm C^5_3$ or $\binom 5 3$, not a mixture.  It is also equal to $\tfrac {5!}{3!2!}$.

Comment: For something like "more than $3$ are defective" you add up the probabilities that exactly $3$, exactly $4$, exactly $5$ are defective.

Answer (score 1):

The notation should be either $\mathrm C^5_3$ or $\binom 5 3$, not a mixture.   It is also equal to $\tfrac {5!}{3!~2!}$.

The binomial coefficien, $\mathrm C^5_3$, counts the arrangements of 3 defectives among a sample of 5 (alternatively: ways to select places for the defectives in a line up of the samples).   You *also* need to measure the probability for a *particular* arrangement of three defectives and two nondefectives to occur.   Since each such arrangement is equally probable, multiplying that by the coefficient gives the probability that *some* arrangement of three defectives and two nondefectives will occur.

$${\mathrm C}^5_3~\mathsf P(D)^3~\mathsf P(D^\complement)^2$$